# C: ReSize array

Tags: c, malloc

I've been doing some research about resizing, dynamic allocation, etc. in C. But I still can't quite understand the following:

Imagine I declare an integer array `int vec[1000]` and I fill it with a number sequence that I extract from a file using gets. But, in the end, I ended up using only 100B and not the declared 1000B. How can I eliminate the unused declared space?

Comment: You can't resize a declared array.  You can only resize memory allocated through `malloc`, `realloc`, etc.

Comment: `char * vec = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000); ...... char * v = realloc(vec, sizeof(int) * 100);  if (v == 0) { ..error not enough memory, but you can continue to use vec.. } else vec = v;`

Comment: Please do not include "thanks", or even worse "Thanks in advanceD" in your questions. See here: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it and here: meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/… for more information.

Comment: `int vec[1000]` is not dynamically allocated, so yeah, then you're pretty much stuck with it. You do not have that problem with dynamic allocation (but you may have others).